# CQRS + event sourcing based reactive applications: How to?

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, event-sourcing

Considering an architecture where events from some kind of source pop in at any time. We have a command side consisting of event handlers that receive those events and store them in a database. In addition, the event handlers asynchronously call services that analyze the events and create a prepared view. On the query side, we have back-end services (say based on spring webflux or any other kind of reactive extension) and a consuming web service (e.g. an Angular single page application) that is supposed to be updated at each incoming event event.

Since most (or all, I just don't know) SQL databases (like e.g. MariaDB) don't support reactions based on data-changes. I have to think about another way to tell my service on the query side to update the say `Flux` or whatever is consumed by my front-end.

Is there a best practice to do this, or at least a good solution for this, that doesn't rely on poll times (at best with java spring, and without a need for an additional broker)?

Comment: I don't understand, coukd you clarify your architecture and what you need?

Comment: _"We have a command side"_ Events are not commands. _"the event handlers ... create a prepared view"_ And if that's done you can inform the client. I don't see the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Axon Framework. It has a concept called Subscription Queries which can react to Query side changes. 
Basically what it does is:

> 1. Please provide the current result of this particular query.
> 2. Until I  cancel, if anything changes in these results, please let me know.

1. [Sample Implementation](https://github.com/JayyR/axon-sample)
2. [Axon : Blog about Subscription queries](https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/introducing-subscription-queries)

Comment: This indeed seems to be an interesting framework, especially since it seems to nicely integrate with several databases an spring framework. On the way searching, I also found that mongodb no has similar functionality in their own connector, but the implementation in spring didn't work when I've tried it. However, thanks for your reply. If this framework will be the final solution for me, I'll accept it as the answer.